# Combination of exponentional and uniform distribuion problem

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be uniform distributed in $[0, 1]$. Let $Υ$ be exponenential distributed with $θ = 1$. Let $Y$ that is defined by tossing a fair coin and if tails comes up then $Z=X$, else if heads comes up, then $Z=Y$.
Any **hint** on how can i calculate $P(Z<0.5)$?

Comment: This seems like it is confused by changing variable names (and the use of "letters" for "tails," perhaps?), but it *sounds* like that $Z$ is a random variable that is either uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$ (i.e., $X$) with probability $1/2$, or exponentially distributed with parameter $1$ (i.e., $Y$) also with probability $1/2$.  Is that right?

Comment: @BrianTung Yep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\mathbb P(Z < 1/2) = \mathbb P(Z < 1/2 \mid \text{heads})\times\mathbb P(\text{heads}) + \mathbb P(Z < 1/2 \mid \text{tails})\times\mathbb P(\text{tails}).$$